# dropdownlist with values but disabled

Tags: c#, asp.net

Hi i need to display a  dropdownlist with data but disable, my problem it's then despite i set the only value that i need to show at the beginning of the application when i set enable false the data it's been clear, so i need to know if exit's another way to disable a dropdown but with data. Thanks

**My Code**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
            //Initialize the combo
            Dictionary<int,String> estate = new Dictionary<int,String>();
            estadosVenezuela.Add(0,"Pick a state");
            DropDownList2.DataValueField = "Key";
            DropDownList2.DataTextField = "Value";
            DropDownList2.DataBind();
            DropDownList2.Enabled = false;
}
```

i need that the values pick a state appear's but with the dropdownlist disabled

Comment: Does estadosVenezuela get added to the DropDownList2? What is the type of estadosVenezuela?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to specify your DropDownList2.DataSource. Right now it's not being set so the list has nothing in it.